# How do I get the value of the previous row and perform calculation based on it?

Tags: sql-server

How do I get the previous row value for `field1` and multiply it times 2?

Initially, there will always be something in the first row to start things off. All other field1 values will always be null to begin with.

```
DECLARE @varTable1 Table
(
[id] [int],
[field1] [decimal](18,4)
)

INSERT INTO @varTable1
VALUES
(1,20),
(2,NULL),
(3,NULL),
(4,NULL)

SELECT * FROM @varTable1
```

Expected:

```
id  field1
1   20.0000
2   40.0000
3   80.0000
4   160.0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can just `SUM` the value of `field1` and then multiply it by a power of `2`:

```sql
SELECT Id,
       SUM(field1) OVER () * POWER(2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) - 1)
FROM @varTable1 vT1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kt5oMyDM)

Comment: Exactly, I was about to suggest this `SELECT id, field1 = (POWER(2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) * FIRST_VALUE(field1) OVER (ORDER BY id)) FROM @varTable1` as a possible solution.